# How can I make the MySQL table searching executed faster?

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

The table contains approximately 42.000.000 rows.

The structure is:

```
+----+------+-------+
| id | name | descr |
+----+------+-------+
|  1 | blah | blahd |
+----+------+-------+
```

ID is INT(11) PRIMARY
name is VARCHAR(420) INDEX
descr is MEDIUMTEXT - FULLTEXT

The search query is:

```
SELECT id,name,descr FROM infotbl WHERE name LIKE '%la%' LIMIT 20
```

And the query takes more than 60seconds.

I read various posts and questions but the only I found was KEYS, INDEXES and the use of MATCH () AGAINST () instead of LIKE %%.

MATCH - AGAINST didn't result as desired.
Although KEYS and INDEXES make the search much faster it is still extremely slow.

I thought to split the table to smaller tables infotbl_1, infotbl_2 etc, or make partitions but these may result slower results.

I also changed the table TYPE/ENGINE from InnoDB to MyISAM and it made it about 20-30 times faster but it is still extremely slow.

Comment: Is your search always for the same pattern `'%la%'`, or do you need to search for different patterns?

Comment: A like operator with a leading wildcard character cannot use any index, including fulltext. If you are searching for names, then fulltext index /boolean search combo can potentially help as people usually search for the start of a first name or surname, not really somewhere in the middle or at the end. However, if you want complete fexibility in searching, then you have to live with a slow query.

Comment: @Bill Karwin: The search string is changing but it is always short usually one two words.

Comment: @easleyfixed: The name column is used for searching that it's already varchar. And I have tested various versions of MySQL and the latest MySQL 5 gave the fastest results.

Comment: @easleyfixed Citation required. Why do you think MEDIUMTEXT takes more space than VARCHAR to store the same string?

Comment: You should use full-text indexing for this. But note that by default it only indexes words of 4 characters or longer, so `la` won't be optimized.

Comment: @easleyfixed the search is done on the name field only, not on the description one.

Comment: the only way to speed this up would be to use fulltext on name, which can't look for substrings, only matching "words" (with a minimum length).   show some realistic examples of searches and data

Comment: Oh yeah you are right on that @Shadow, perhaps it would be faster in its curent format (index value instead of the text string) than so it doesn't have to read the text field so i guess disregard my suggestions on this one.

Comment: If you can switch to postgreSQL you can get a kind of indexing that *will* help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69216373/postgres-select-ilike-text-is-slow-on-large-string-rows/69223762#69223762

Comment: @O. Jones: The indexing of MySQL is much faster than postegreSQL

Comment: Maybe so, but postgreSQL has trigram indexes suitable for speeding up `col LIKE '%searchterm%'`.